# UICollectionview lags with local stored images

Tags: ios, uicollectionview

I have simple application, who consumes data from local core data storage. I am displaying images in collectionview & it lags when i scroll. All images are from local bundle itself.
Can anyone help?
Thanx.

Answer (score 0):

A typical solution to this would be to use the proxy design pattern and to load images asynchronously on a background thread.

You could have a UIImageView subclass that shows a placeholder image or a blank rectangle, but that is automatically updated once the image has been loaded. Some apps even use this to make a fancy "polaroid fade" effect, i.e. fade the image from white or black when it goes on-screen.

To prevent placeholder images from ever being seen (although you'd want to test this on device, as local storage might be fast enough to make this unnoticeable), you could pre-cache images in advance (for example by anticipating a number of extra rows in your cellForRowAtIndexPath method)

Answer (score 0):

Store all the images in an array once and use that array instead of fetching images from core data everytime the cell loads.